# How to pass NULL value from Unidac Query component in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, sybase, devart, unidac

When I am using StoredProc component in Delphi using 
`ParamByname('ParamName').Clear` I'm able to send NULL value.

But how can I pass NULL value when using a Query component?

```
with Query do
begin
 SQL.ADD('exec d_upd_calc'+Quoted(EditCalc.Text));
end
```

In the above scenario I want to send NULL if the edit box is blank.

I am using Delphi 2010, Unidac with Sybase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in Queries you can work with parameters:

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'exec d_upd_calc :myparam';
Query.Prepare;
Query.ParamByName('myparam').Clear;
```

And it's better to use parameters than to build the complete string, because you must not handle quotes and avoid security leaks via SQL-injection.

Comment: Addition: you may need to specify parameter data type `DataType := ftString` or how else.

Answer (score 1):

With Advantage DB I would do something along these lines:

```
var
  sqlText: string;

with Query do
begin
  if EditCalc.Text = '' then
    sqlText := 'exec d_upd_calc NULL' else
    sqlText := 'exec d_upd_calc '+Quoted(EditCalc.Text);
  SQL.ADD(sqlText);
end;
```

If the keyword is also `NULL` then this should work.

Does `Quoted` remove/escape any dangerous user input to prevent SQL injection? If yes then it's good. If not then it should.

Comment: if Trim(CalcType.Text) <> '' then Calc:= Quoted(Trim(CalcType.Text)) else Calc := 'Null'; Before add to SQL am giving as Quoted..So it is not giving issue now..thanks